# Set limits on individual axis objects (XAxis or YAxis)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a plot for which some of the setup is shared between the x- and the y-axis. For that reason I planned to move this setup to a separate function. Usually attributes of the individual axes can be set via dedicated methods such as `set_[xy]ticks, set_[xy]lim, ...` of the `AxesSubplot` object. On the other hand there exist also corresponding methods for the `[XY]Axis` objects such as `ax.xaxis.set_ticks` - well, except for `set_lim`; this method doesn't exist and I couldn't find an equivalent. Is there a reason it doesn't exist on the individual axis objects and is there a way I can set the limit on these nonetheless?

Here's some sample code, illustrating the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def setup(axis, positions, labels):
    axis.grid()
    axis.set_ticks([positions[x] for x in labels])
    axis.set_ticklabels(labels)
    # axis.set_lim([min(positions.values()),  # 'set_lim' does not exist though
    #               max(positions.values())])


positions = dict(zip('abcdef', range(6)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
setup(ax.xaxis, positions, list('ace'))
setup(ax.yaxis, positions, list('bdf'))
ax.set_xlim([0, 5])  # need to set the limits here
ax.set_ylim([0, 5])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for `axes.Axes.set_xlim` is something like 60 lines long and checks a lot of things related to axis scale, units, sharing and autoscaling behaviour etc. In particular for autoscaling, the two axes are not completely independent. Therefore this resides in `axes.Axes` instead of `axis.Axis`.

This is however not a problem. Every `Axis` knows about its parent `Axes` via the `.axes` attribute. I.e. `ax.set_xlim(..)` is the same as

```
ax.xaxis.axes.set_xlim(..)
```

Comment: Actually this is what I ended up using, but since I want it to work on both `xaxis` and `yaxis` I used `getattr(axis.axes, f'set_{type(axis).__name__.lower()[0]}lim')(...)` which is a bit weird, so I hoped for a cleaner approach. I see that if `[XY]Axis` dispatched `set_lim` to `self.axes.set_[xy]lim` this would falsely convey the notion that this is an independent operation on a single axis. So maybe it's best to stay with `ax.set_[xy]lim` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function set_view_interval (see documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_view_interval.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_view_interval)) should do the job:

```
axis.set_view_interval(min(positions.values()), max(positions.values()))
```

In the documentation, you can also find more information about setting axis data and axis view limits [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axis_api.html?highlight=xaxis) (section *Data and view intervals*).

Comment: Well, as the documentation states: *Set the axis view limits.  **This method is for internal use**; Matplotlib users should typically use e.g. `~Axes.set_xlim` and `~Axes.set_ylim`.*

Comment: I see, your approach is indeed much more convenient.